# Google fit - automatic activities not found through SessionApi

Tags: google-fit

For those automatic activities, i.e. users don't open the google fit app to manually track the event, they were recorded automatically. We can't find them through the `SessionAPI`. Do you guys know how to solve this?

I've tried to use `HistoryAPI` to track the activities, but the payload doesn't include `calorie` information.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/SessionsApi):

> **Sessions** are a way of storing user-visible groups of related stream
>   data in a useful and shareable manner, and allow for easy querying of
>   the data in a detailed or aggregated fashion.

This for inserting fitness data with session metadata.

Youtube `Sessions API` payload contains:

> ```
> {
>   "session": [
>     {
>       "id": string,
>       "name": string,
>       "description": string,
>       "startTimeMillis": long,
>       "endTimeMillis": long,
>       "modifiedTimeMillis": long,
>       "application": {
>         "packageName": string,
>         "version": string,
>         "detailsUrl": string,
>         "name": string
>       },
>       "activityType": integer,
>       "activeTimeMillis": long
>     }
>   ],
>   "deletedSession": [
>     {
>       "id": string,
>       "name": string,
>       "description": string,
>       "startTimeMillis": long,
>       "endTimeMillis": long,
>       "modifiedTimeMillis": long,
>       "application": {
>         "packageName": string,
>         "version": string,
>         "detailsUrl": string,
>         "name": string
>       },
>       "activityType": integer,
>       "activeTimeMillis": long
>     }
>   ],
>   "nextPageToken": string,
>   "hasMoreData": boolean
> }
> ```

Here are the [list](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/activity-types) of `activityType` property.

I recommend that you use [`HistoryAPI`](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history) that enables your app to perform bulk operations on the fitness store: reading, inserting, updating, and deleting fitness data. You can create a [DataRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/) to get **calories** burned for each activity performed within the specified time range.